# Codename One - iPhone app "ipa" and Android "apk" files on a device farm

Tags: codenameone

Can I manually test an "ipa" or "apk" file generated by Codename One on a device farm, like using a real device?

I have this doubt because, on the AWS Device Farm FAQs, it's written so: «My app is obfuscated. Can I still test my app on AWS Device Farm? Yes, if you use ProGuard. If you use DexGuard with anti-piracy measures, we are unable to re-sign the app and run tests against it.»

I know that the apps generated by Codename One are obfuscated, that's why I don't know if I can use them on Amazon device farm.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We use the default proguard not dexguard so there shouldn't be a problem with Amazon. You can also disable the proguard obfuscation stage entirely with the [build hints](https://www.codenameone.com/manual/advanced-topics.html).

Comment: Do you refer to the "android.enableProguard" build hint? Is only Android obfuscated?

Comment: Proguard is used in Android and some legacy platforms (RIM/J2ME). Other platforms have their own obfuscation flags that are different. iOS uses native compilation and the symbols are stripped so obfuscation isn't necessary.